# SQL Reporting Services Filter Select All Auto Run

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am creating a report with SQL reporting services.
VS 2008 SQL 2008.

I created a filter for dates and distinct values. For dates I created two filters/parameters for date ranges and was able to successfully run the report on first click.

However when creating a filter for distinct values and drop down. I am unable to figure out how to run the reports on first click. It keeps forcing me to choose a selection. I want it to run on the first click with the "Select All" option already selected.

What am I missing? The Dataset query contains the dates while I added the drop down one through the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [these instructions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281306%28SQL.100%29.aspx) to set default values. You'll want to use the **Get values from a query** option. Point the default parameter to the dataset that is being used to generate the list of distinct values.

Comment: I was doing that but still nothing. However my dataset that was generating the unique list was allowing null and blanks. WHen I fixed that, that seem to do it. THere also seems to be differences between adding the parameters in the query of the dataset and not through the gui. A combination of these issue was causing my problems. THanks ALss well.